laravel filament v.3 problem with validation message on create
I'm getting to know laravel filament, and I have a problem when sending the form to create it with the "Create" button, the error messages don't appear only in the native browser,

but if I send "Create & create another" the voices are displayed.

I've been struggling with this for a while, do you have experience with it?
Thank you
I would like the error messages to be displayed in the same way during create and edit

I have a problem to add transaltion like on the 1st picture.
how you translate first message (with the exclamation mark)?

Those inputs have required property and create button type is "submit" that's why inputs are validated in HTML first.
You can use laravel validations for it. Remove ->required() method and use rule method

Instead of required(), use it like this:
Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
    // ->required()
    ->rules(['required'])
    ->markAsRequired()

